# Parsing a JSON value in Objective-C with variable ID/key

Tags: objective-c, json, key

I have searched this extensively, but so far I could not find a question that matches my problem. I have a 'unique' JSON output and trying to parse it in Objective-C.

First of all, this is the JSON that I must parse:

```
{
"code": 1,
"req": {
    "123": [ //this can be different all the time
        {
            "item_id": "44",
            "item_value": "the value",
            "item_code": "21z"
        },
        {
            "item_id": "45",
            "item_value": "another value",
            "item_code": "l30"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

As can be seen above, the "123" right under "req" can vary, so I can't hardcode the value there in my Objective-C.

So far i have been trying to use NSMutableDictionary to receive the HTTP response:

```
NSMutableDictionary dict = [NSJSONserializationWithData:responseData options:options error:&error];
NSArray *array = [[dict objectForKey@"req"];
```

But from here I don't know how to specify the variable (123) key.. because it can differ everytime.

Comment: Are you guaranteed that there will only be one object in the "req" dictionary?

Comment: No there could be multiple objects in req.

Answer (score 0):

Is there going to be multiple arrays in the "req" object?

If not you could loop through the objects inside the "req" object checking if the object's type matches an NSArray

e.g.

```
for(id obj in array)
{
    if([obj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
         //123 object = obj
    }
}
```

Comment: It's possible that there will be multiple arrays in req, with different values.